# Types comparison in VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, types

How i can compare type data type in VB.NET?
My code:

```
Private Function Equal(ByVal parameter As String, ByVal paramenterName As String, ByVal dataType As Type) As String

    If dataType = String Then
        return 1;
    End If

 End Function
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Can you choose a different answer as the selected answer you chose has a syntax error in vb.net?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The accepted answer has a syntax error. Here is the correct solution:

```
If dataType = GetType(String) Then
    Return 1
End If
```

Or

```
 If dataType.Equals(GetType(String)) Then
      Return 1
 End If
```

Or

```
 If dataType Is GetType(String) Then
     Return 1
 End If
```

The last way is probably the best way to check because it won't throw an exception if the object is null.

Also see https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.object.gettype(v=vs.110).aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=vb#code-snippet-1

Answer (score 29):

```
If dataType = GetType(String) Then
    return 1
End If
```

Comment: I got a compile error when trying this in VS 2013 Express - the below suggestion to use "type Is GetType()" worked for me, though.

Comment: Hi Darin, your solution appears to no longer be valid in VB.NET.  As the accepted answer, can you please update it, so that it remains valid?

Comment: Syntax error. Should not have semi colon but StackOverflow's ridiculous rules won't let you edit one character in an invalid answer.

Answer (score 25):

```
If datatype Is GetType(String) Then
    'do something
End If
```

Substitute `Is` for `=` and everything works

Answer (score 1):

This is probably the best way to do it in VB.

```
If dataType Is String Then
    return 1
End If
```

Comment: This will not work. You have to use GetType(String), because the Is operator compares two objects and String is a type not an object.

Comment: If TypeOf dataType is String

Comment: `TypeOf dataType` won't work, because it returns `Type`, not `String`. `dataType Is GetType(String)` is the correct way to check the type, as mentioned in the other answers.